# Не запускается эмулятор Android

Tags: android-sdk, android

Установил JDK, Eclipse Helios, Android SDK, Eclipse Android (ADT или Android Development Tool)... все свежее. Проблема в том, что при запуске даже самого простейшего `Hello Word!` не запускается эмулятор. Подскажите, может какой параметр конфигурации упустил или еще какие премудрости...
В консоли выводится следующая информация:

> [2011-06-16 22:44:35 - HelloDNS] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'A_2_2' 
>   [2011-06-16 22:44:35 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
>   [2011-06-16 22:44:35 - Emulator] Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

Comment: Пробовали сам эмулятор запустить?
Что пишет Eclipse при попытке запуска?

Comment: [2011-06-16 22:44:35 - HelloDNS] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'A_2_2'
[2011-06-16 22:44:35 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
[2011-06-16 22:44:35 - Emulator] Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Гугл в помощь:

> На диске С (или на том, где установлена Ваша текущая ОС), есть папка .android (именно с точкой в начале). Обычно она находится по адресу `C:\Users\имя_вашей_учетки\.android` (это для Vista и 7). Нужно, чтобы на пути к папке .android не встречались русские символы, т.е. имя учетной записи не должно быть на русском языке."

[Источник](http://itblog.name/archives/678), в комментариях.

Вариант 2:

> Нужно создать переменную окружения `Windows ANDROID_SDK_HOME` и присвоить ей значение, например `C:\android`, чтобы в пути не было русских букв." Делается это здесь: "Мой компьютер->свойства->дополнительно->переменные среды".

[Источник](http://www.winline.ru/forum/forum7/topic4332/messages/).

Comment: дело в том, что переменные среды я уже прописал вручную, но эффекта нет...сейчас попробую по вашему мануалу

Comment: Все, удалил старую русскоязычную учетную запись, переставил Eclipse, заново все пути прописал и плагины поставил. Эмулятор заработал. Благодарю за ответ!